# What is this TRS-80 game with castle and maze-like walls?

Tags: game-identification

What is this TRS-80 game with castle and maze-like walls? It appeared in this weeks Wired magazine and looks like a publicity shot.

[image: TRS-80 game]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Ghost's Gallery!](http://archive.org/stream/med-systems-software-spring-1981-catalog-1981/med_systems_software_spring_1981_catalog.1981_djvu.txt)

> Ghost's Gallery is a graphics game for the TRS-80 for one or two  players. A sixty room castle is drawn on the screen. To win, a player must capture the ghost with the key and get to the front door before the ghost or other player captures him.

I've played it (emulated) and talk about it [here](http://www.gdcvault.com/play/1015922/Inspiration-from-the-Trash-The) (29:17)

A lot of great TRS-80 games have no images or YouTube videos.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so I did a **ton** of research into this.

1) I went down [lists TRS-80 games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TRS-80_games), looked up screenshots from each game. None matched.

2) Reverse image searched it, only traced back to number stock photo sites.

3) Found a [higher resolution image](http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/42-20041101.jpg) and searched for the text in the middle of the screen:

```
ERIC: DICE: 2 3 TOTAL=5 USE {arrow keys} D=DONE
```

Which also turned up nothing.

4) Posted to [identification subreddits](http://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/2wzn2d/tomt_this_old_trs80_game_with_what_looks_like_a/), which refered me to /r/trs80.

5) [Posted to /r/trs80](http://www.reddit.com/r/trs80/comments/2x0fii/this_old_trs80_game_with_what_looks_like_a/), and no one there recognized it either. They suggested that it was 
something written in BASIC that was either expressly for the picture, or that it was written then never saw a release.

Honestly, I think it's safe to say that the game never existed as a purchasable game outside of this stock photo.

Comment: I can guarantee that the list of known TRS-80 games is incomplete; I own one, and there's a ton missing.  I wouldn't discount the game not existing.  Good effort, though!

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering how complete the list was. If you could point me to a more complete list, I'll give it one last shot.

Comment: Thanks for working. I too have done really exhaustive searching. The game is actually similar to a certain class of games (Haunted House? I think), I forget the exact titles, but I did find a couple that were close but not exact matches.

Comment: Note: I was mainly using the http://www.mobygames.com/ database but I did use others, including some old scanned in magazines dating from 1980.

Comment: Wow, it's incredible that between all the sources both of us have checked that we haven't turned up anything. I'm genuinely curious now.